# Detecting Custom Object From Any Image Google Cloud Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I want to detect whether or not an image has a specific (custom) object in it or not. I tried to go through the documentation of google cloud vertex ai, but I am confused. I am not an AI or ML engineer.

They provide the following services for image

- Classification (Single Label)
- Classification (Multi Label)
- Image Object Detection
- Image segmentation

Almost All of these features require at least two labels. At least 10 images must be assigned to each label for the features to work.

Now, suppose I have 10 cat images. One of my label name is cat. And then I will have to create another label named non_cat. right? There can be infinite possibilities of an image not having a cat. Does that mean, I upload 10 cat photos and 10 random junk photos in non_cat label??

Currently I have chosen `image object detection`. It detects multiple attributes of that custom object with confidence score. Should I use these score to identify the custom object in my backend application? Am I going into the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to classify an image as cat or non-cat? if yes, Classification can work easily here. Any specific reason you've chosen Image Object Detection?

Comment: The reason behind choosing object detection is that if the object has specific attributes (like logo, custom shapes etc.), i will only consider it acceptable. Lets say a school ID card. It must have a logo, an electronic chip, an ID number, human face, QR code, Signature, watermark etc etc. If someone captures a photo of an elephant, object detection will not find out logo, chip, id no, human face etc etc in it. So i will reject it. That's how I am thinking about approaching the problem. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation in comments you're right going with Object Detection model in this case.

Refer the google documentation on how to [prepare](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/object-detection/prepare-data) the data for object detection model.
As per the documentation, the dataset can have minimum 1 label and can go maximum upto 1000 labels for an AutoML or custom-trained model.

Yes. Afer checking the accuracy of your model, you can utilize the confidence score to identify the object in your application.